Fastest way to check if a SpatRaster has at least one non-NA value?
I am currently using this:
any(as.numeric(terra::global(x, fun = "notNA")[,1]) > 0)

It works fine, but I think terra::global is checking the entire raster. I'm looking for a method that stops when it finds the first non-NA value. This would save considerable time when checking a large SpatRaster.

Not sure where your notNA() comes from, might be slow? Maybe sum is faster. f <- \(r) is.na(global(r, "sum")). Check on r <- rast(ncols=10, nrows=10); values(r) <- replace(1:ncell(r), 5, NA); f(r).

"notNA" is a special function built into terra::global. See: https://rdrr.io/cran/terra/man/global.html

Anyways, tested if "sum" is faster? You could make a feature request for implementing "anyNA" or "stop_at_first_NA" in terra's global, probably written in C++ code.

BTW just noticed that "notNA" returns the number of cells that are not NA, so you could try f <- \(r) {ncell(r) - terra::global(r, fun = "notNA") > 0}; f(r).

?terra::anyNA from Summary-methods is likely quicker, though I haven't read the c++ to see if it stops at 'first contact'. countNA, noNA and allNA would necessarily read tull rast.

@Chris And how to bring terra::anyNA to work in terra::global()?

Drop the global approach as it is not one of the 'enabled' fun = and just test directly if the goal is to discover 'TRUE/FALSE' NA within, terra::anyNA(x), is how one would think it would be used. @kevin, would you benchmark your global above and anyNA (if it works as I suspect on your large x.

Not as I imagined. someNA_mtx <- matrix(c(1, NA), 1000, 1000) ; someNA_rast <- rast(someNA_mtx) ; which(as.data.frame(anyNA(someNA_rast)) == TRUE)[1], that also loads all into memory, anyNA returns a SpatRast, not T/F, though those values could be extracted - quickly? unique(values(someNA_rast))      lyr.1 [1,]     1 [2,]    NA
